# How to use different colors for each item when selected in BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview

My question is how can I use different a color for each item in BottomNavigationView design in android? for example if I have 4 items: item 1 would be green when selected, item 2 blue ,...
Here is my .xml code:

```
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        app:itemIconSize="24dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

**Update:**
 I found the solution if we just use icons without labels and it was simple; for each item(in this example: home) we make a drawable like *home_icon.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_speech_bubble_green_36"/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_speech_bubble_green_36"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_speech_bubble_black_36"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_speech_bubble_black_36"/>
</selector>
```

And in the menu we do this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ....

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Awesome but i cant reproduce...your solve...

Comment: @user8309756 Can u upload minimal source and send me link?

Comment: I solve!!!Tnx!! simple add bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null); in onCreate() and use other png

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately u can't change different color for for each item.but u can use custom bottomsheet with framelayout.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/StyleRoot"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/FView"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            style="@style/LineShadow"
            android:layout_height="1.5dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nav_home"
                style="@style/NavLinearView"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="22dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/selector_nav_home" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/txt_home"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/selector_nav_text"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:font_name="@string/font_rg" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nav_tasks"
                style="@style/NavLinearView"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="22dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/selector_nav_tasks" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/txt_tasks"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/selector_nav_text"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:font_name="@string/font_rg" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
                style="@style/NavLinearView"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="22dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/selector_nav_profile" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/txt_profile"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/selector_nav_text"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:font_name="@string/font_rg" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I am looking for.